# Returning struct with function pointers - pointers get corrupted

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, stack, function-pointers

I am trying to stub out a module for unit testing.
The module that I am stubbing out uses a struct that contains set of function pointers.
Also it provides and API that assign desired function pointers to struct and returns pointer that struct back to the user.

My problem is that in the user layer function pointers would point to garbage (something else than in stub layer). However if I pass in that pointer to the struct that contains function pointers back into stub layer they are correct and I am able to call those functions.

module_A.c:

```
struct generic_intf {
    int (*open)(struct generic_intf *intf);
    void (*close)(struct generic_intf *intf);
};

struct generic_intf *intf = intf_load(some_enum);

printf( "user addr of intf: %p\n", ( void * )intf);
printf( "user addr of intf->open: %p\n", ( void * )intf->open);

helper_function(intf);    

intf->open(intf); //fatal: Illegal Instruction Signal
```

stub.c:

```
static int dummy_open(struct ipmi_intf *intf);
static void dummy_close(struct ipmi_intf *intf);

struct generic_intf dummy_intf = {
    open:       dummy_open,
    close:      dummy_close,
};

struct generic_intf *intf_load(enum)
{
    //switch case on enum
        return &dummy_intf;
}

void helper_function(struct generic_intf *intf)
{
    printf( "stub addr of intf: %p\n", ( void * )intf);
    printf( "stub addr of intf->open: %p\n", ( void * )intf->open);
    intf->open(intf); //works just as intended
}
```

As output I would get something along this:

```
user addr of intf: 0x612560
user addr of intf->open: 0x40ef23
stub addr of intf: 0x612560
stub addr of intf->open: 0x404556
```

Is this something to do with stack? But then how actual module work normally and my UTs run into this problem?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg sorry it was a typo

Comment: First of all, you should not have to cast those pointers in the `printf` calls. In C any pointer can implicitly be converted to `void *`. Secondly, there's nothing in the code you show that changes the `open` pointer. But how does your `dummy_open` look like? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us instead?

Comment: What's `return &dummy_intf`? Are you returning the address of a local variable by any chance?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `printf` is a vararg function and default argument promotion don't include conversion from structure types to `void *`. The cast is useless on most (all?) systems, but I think, the standard requires them for strictly conforming code.

Comment: @mafso You mean "from pointer to structure type"? But yeah, you're probably right.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Ahh, yes, of course: pointer to structure type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: @mafso is right. More interestingly, you can **not** convert a function pointer to any object pointer, including `void *` with any kind of defined behaviour. In practice though, it will probably work just fine. The only sure-fire way to examine the value of a function pointer is through an `unsigned char` array (and perhaps also through the other two character types).

Comment: Could it be something to do with `dummy_open`? Can you post the code for that?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to reproduce the problem. Please try @JoachimPileborg's advice of posting an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that compiles and demonstrates the behavior you're seeing. I tried to create one based on the code that you posted, but I was unable to recreate the problem, even if I compile the stub as a dynamic library (so/dll/dylib).

Comment: there seems a high probability that the *intf is pointing to some stack area in side intf_load() and that stack is not yet corrupted when the original printf functions are called, but after calling another function helper_function which uses the same stack area, AND the calls to printf use the same stack area, so the *intf is pointing to a corrupted area.  Try using a static area in the intf_load function for the instance of the struct.